# Is there any way to access Firebase Firestore database from C# server side using FirebaseAdmin?

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, google-cloud-firestore, server-side

I have added the FirebaseAdmin SDK Nuget package provided by Google and tried different classes provide by SDK
e.g.

```
string baseURL = "default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/";
string tablename = "sample-default-rtdb";
string appName = "Image-Sample";

AppOptions appOptions = new AppOptions(){
ServiceAccountId = "asdf",
Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json"),
ProjectId = appName
};

//FirebaseApp firebaseApp = new FirebaseApp();
var create = FirebaseApp.Create(appOptions);
```

But I do not understand where do I add the path to ServiceAccountKey and also how do I access the Firestore or real-time database instance.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and that show C# SDK does not support firestore and realtime database.

You can use firestore on C# server with following step.
[Set up your development environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment)